# How to split data in multiple sheets while exporting data from ReportViewer 10 to Excel?

Tags: asp.net, excel, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I am using Report Viewer 10, now I am exporting data into Excel but it's give me error: 

`Excel Rendering Extension: Number of rows exceeds the maximum possible rows per sheet in this format; Rows Requested: 73879, Max Rows: 65536`
.

Can we split data in multiple sheets?

Answer (score 3):

Set the property "Pagebreak" on the tablix or table or other element to force a new tab.

These links can give you some more idea:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Exports to report viewer will split to multiple sheets if you have your data on multiple pages in your Report.  This may not be possible for you?

If you export to CSV format from report viewer you can have more than 65K lines, and you can open it in Excel.  You loose formatting, but you get the data. This format is also better for applying pivots in Excel as you don't get blank cells in the data.

Comment: No Vivian, in my report I have simple table with 10 columns.

Comment: Have you tried CSV format to export to?  Would this work for you?